Identify the episode of 80-90's TV show ALF
I watched that episode when I was 6 so I don't clearly remember which episode it was or what season, because it aired in the 90's in India after it was actually ended. 
The only thing I remember from that episode is that ALF is sitting on the sofa and is cracking the peanuts' shell between his shoulder and head. 

It might be difficult, I watched almost all episode of Season 1 and some episode of season 2 but didn't find that episode. If you know what episode it was I would be really thankful! 

Yikes, that can't be easy. Would you settle for an episode where Alf cracks peanut shells with a dummy's head? (Happens in the episode I'm Your Puppet where Alf gets into ventriloquism. It's available on Youtube).

Yup it might not be an easy job. I will check that out on YouTube.

@Walt Yes!! I watched the episode and it is it! My memory was still blurry, but when I watched the scene where he cracks the peanut with the puppet I became sure. I was just confused if it was ALF who cracked the peanut or something else. Thanks! :D

No problem. :) I'll put it up.

In Season 2, Episode 23 (I'm Your Puppet), Alf starts a ventriloquist act but the dummy takes over his life. In one scene it demands peanuts, so Alf obliges and smashes the shells with the dummy's head:


EDIT: Shiz Z. has commented that the episode seems meta-textual, and he might be on to something. This episode, which was written by Al Jean and Mike Reiss (who both worked on The Simpsons later on), features an obnoxious puppet called Paul who bosses Alf around, annoys the whole family and even threatens to 'replace' the parents.
It's worth noting, then, that the show's creator and main puppeteer, Paul Fusco, wasn't easy to work with. The puppeteering meant a much longer shooting schedule, as well as many trenches dug around the set that the actors had to constantly navigate. There was also tension between Paul and Max Wright (Willie), who claimed Alf was getting all the best lines. Some of the cast described Alf as a miserable experience.
So was this self-parody or someone's attempt to vent? Whatever it was, it certainly seems intentional, and in light of a blooper reel on Youtube [WARNING: CONTAINS PROFANITY AND A RACIAL SLUR] where Paul Fusco is pretending Alf has Tourette's, this line from the episode is particularly suspicious:

It's Paul. He's using the dummy to blow off steam.


That was a damn creepy episode. I hate ventriloquist dummies to this day thanks to it.

Now that you mention, the show ALF had quite a few disturbing moments IIRC. I wish I could remember this episode... seems like some kind of "meta" thing going on, with the puppet serving as a ventriloquist LOL
